# Spring Boot restarting after static files changed

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I have a Spring Boot project with a static website (just css, js, html). I added Spring Boot Dev Tools to the project. When I change some static file, then click "Run" > "Reload Changed Classes", Spring Boot (Tomcat) restarts.

[image]

This happens in Windows. However, the same exact project in Mac behaves fine - it just quickly loads the static files.
I even exported/imported settings to IntelliJ but the problem persists. Any clue why this happens?

Comment: Might be your safari browser has liveReload extension. Does it ?

Comment: I'm using Chrome in both cases and they're synch'ed in terms of extensions.

Comment: And none has live reload  extension